# SQL Server: using table lock hint in select for ensuring correctness?

Tags: sql-server, select, hints

I've got a project that is trying to apply DDD (Domain Driven Design). Currently, we've got something like this:

```
begin tran
 try
  _manager.CreateNewEmployee(newEmployeeCmd);
  tran.Commit();
 catch
  rollback tran
```

Internally, the CreateNewEmployee method uses a domain service for checking if there's already an employee with the memberId. Here's some pseudo code:

```
void CreateNewEmployee(NewEmployeeCmd cmd)
  if(_duplicateMember.AlreadyRegistered(cmd.MemberId) )
    throw duplicate
  // extra stuff
  saveNewEmployee()
end
```

Now, in the end, it's as if we have the following SQL instructions executed (pesudo code again):

```
begin sql tran
 select count(*) from table where memberId=@memberId and status=1 -- active
 --some time goes by
 insert into table ...
end
```

NOw, when I started looking at the code, I've noticed that it was using the default SQL Server locking level. In practice, that means that something like this could happen:

```
--thread 1
(1)select ... --assume it returns 0
--thread 2
(2)select ... ---nothing found
(3)insert recordA
--thread 1
(4)insert record --some as before
(5) commit tran
--thread 1
(6) commit tran
```

So, we could end up having repeated records. I've tried playing with the transaction levels, but the only way I've managed to make it work like it's intended was by changing the select that is used to check if there's already a record in the table. I've ended up using a table lock hint which instructs sql to maintain a lock until the end of the transaction. That was the only way I've managed to get a lock when the select starts (changing the other isolation levels still wouldn't do what I needed since they all allowed the select to run)

So, I've ended up using a table lock which is held from the beginning until the end of the transaction. In practice, that means that step (2) will block until thread 1 ends its job.

Is there a better option for this kind of scenarios (that don't depend on using, say, indexes)?

Thanks.

Luis

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the proper locks on the initial `select`, which you can do with the locking hints `with (updlock, serializable)`. Once you do that, thread 2 will wait for thread 1 to finish if thread 2 is using the same key range in its `where`.

You could use the [Sam Saffron upsert approach](https://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx).

For example:

```
create procedure dbo.Employee_getset_byName (@Name nvarchar(50), @MemberId int output) as
begin
  set nocount, xact_abort on;
  begin tran;
    select  @MemberId = Id
      from  dbo.Employee with (updlock, serializable) /* hold key range for @Name */
      where Name = @Name;
    if @@rowcount = 0 /* if we still do not have an Id for @Name */
    begin;
    /* for a sequence */
      set @MemberId = next value for dbo.IdSequence; /* get next sequence value */
      insert into dbo.Employee (Name, Id)
        values (@Name, @MemberId);
    /* for identity */
      insert into dbo.Employee (Name)
        values (@Name);
      set @MemberId = scope_identity();
    end;
  commit tran;
end;
go
```

Comment: Hello. Currently, I'm using the tablockx and xlock hints (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table). In my case, I'm only interested in inserting if it's not there. Thanks